# Can we sleep and wake up machine using adb commands?

Tags: java, android, python, python-2.7, adb

Is there command to sleep and wake up machine using adb.

e.g. to reboot 'adb reboot'.

Comment: Type `adb` at the command line to get a list of available commands. If it's not there, it's not available.

Comment: reboot is not same as sleep.

Comment: You keep asking essentially the same questions over and over, and apparently have not yet read through `adb`s self-documentation.